# Lucene Wildcard Search doesn't seem to rewrite the query like it does for Fuzzy Search

Tags: java, lucene

When I look at at the **explain** of a fuzzy query I can see it has replaced my existing search term

```
artist:republica~0.5
```

with all the terms in documents that matched

```
(artist:republic^0.78 artist:republica^1.04 artist:republice^0.80888885)
```

But a wildcard query doesnt seem to

```
artist:republica*
```

gives

```
ConstantScore(artist:republica*^1.04)^1.04
```

Why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I thought all multi-term queries used the same rewrite method but reading of the Javadocs I realise that fuzzy query uses a different rewrite method to wildcard and prefix queries.

FuzzyQuery:
MultiTermQuery.TopTermsScoringBooleanQueryRewrite

WildcardQuery:
MultiTermQuery.ConstantScoreAutoRewrite